# C# Zero-One Multiple OverflowException using ULong

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I am trying to find the smallest zero-one number (a number that composes of only zeroes and ones i.e. 11001) that is a multiple of the number input through STDIN, but the program crashes when i input 99999, and this is one of the test cases that should work as the input value should range between 1 and 100000, the program crashes at
**ulong.Parse(binary);** in Getmultiple(ulong n).

What change should i make for it to work ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            ulong l;
            ulong.TryParse(s, out l);

            Console.WriteLine(Getmultiple(l));
        }
    }

    private static ulong Getmultiple(ulong n)
    {

        for (ulong i = 1; ; i++)
        {
            String binary = Convert.ToString((long) i, 2);

            ulong no = ulong.Parse(binary);

            if (no % n == 0)
            {
                return no;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

> **ERROR MESSAGE:**
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Value was either too large or too
>   small for a UInt64.

Comment: Might be easier to just walk over the characters rather than doing this. `let isValid = !s.Any(c => c != '1' && c != '0')`.

Comment: The input from STDIN, in this case stored in 's' is not a zero-one number that i need to validate (its value can range from 1 to 100000), it's the output should be the zero-one number, i am using Convert.ToString((long) i, 2); to get the binary numbers (base 2)

Comment: I would guess there is no "zero-one" multiple of 99,999 under 2^64, that is the max value of ulong...

Comment: You might be correct @pseudoDust, maybe it is above 2^64, is there any way i can output such a number, i am required to output all valid zero-one numbers for inputs ranging from 1 to 100000?

Comment: @A.Bhuttoo use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, please include the text of error messages you receive.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overflowing the unsigned long variable, meaning that there isn't a multiple of 99999 fitting your requirements that's also less than 2^64. If you refactor your code to use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of unsigned long, then you won't have the overflow problem. It might take some time for your algorithm to find the solution, though...

I'd also make this change, to sanity check your input:

```
BigInteger l;
if(BigInteger.TryParse(s, out l))
    Console.WriteLine(Getmultiple(l));
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer");
```

Comment: Thanks! this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are getting too large of a number for  `ulong no`, you can use `ulong.TryParse` to avoid this.

```
    private static ulong Getmultiple(ulong n)
    {

        for (ulong i = 1; ; i++)
        {
            String binary = Convert.ToString((long)i,2);

            ulong no = 0;

            if (ulong.TryParse(binary,out no))
            {

                if (no % n == 0)
                {
                    return no;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

I chose to return 0 for an invalid result.

Comment: This is a good workaround to avoid getting the exception, but as @pseudoDust mentioned, there might be no zero-one multiple of 99,999 under 2^64, and i would require to output that value which is above 2^64 in this case, outputting a zero is not a valid output.

Answer (score 0):

> Using BigInteger works!! Some testcases that failed with ulong are now
>   working, thanks Esoteric Screen Name!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            BigInteger l;
            if (BigInteger.TryParse(s, out l))
                Console.WriteLine(Getmultiple(l));
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer");
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger Getmultiple(BigInteger n)
    {

        for (BigInteger i = 1; ; i++)
        {
            String binary = Convert.ToString((long) i, 2);

            BigInteger no = BigInteger.Parse(binary);

            if (no % n == 0)
            {
                return no;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `i` does not need to be `BigInteger` only `no` does. In fact, your `Convert.ToString((long) i, 2);` will fail once `i` does become too big. You should leave `i` as `long` or `ulong`.